# Node JS Post Message

Tags: node.js, express

Am learning node and express JS atm

My app server is like this

```
    require('./retrieveresults.js')();
    require('./addresults.js')();
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();
    const PORT = 8080;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    //view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

    var router = express.Router();

// simple post Employee API --> sample inserting data --> use postman to execute
router.post('/addemployee', function (request, res) {
    console.log(request.body)
    var empid = request.body.empid;
    var fname = request.body.fname;
    var lname = request.body.lname;
    var email = request.body.email;
    var phonenumber = request.body.phonenumber;
    var hire_date = request.body.hire_date
    var job_id = request.body.job_id;
    var salary = request.body.salary;
    var comm_pt = request.body.comm_pt;
    var manager = request.body.manager;
    var department_id = request.body.department_id;
    addDB("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (" + empid + "," + "'"+ fname + "'"+ "," + "'"+ lname + "'"+ "," + "'"+ email + "'"+ "," + "'"+ phonenumber + "'"+ "," + "TO_DATE("+ "'"+ hire_date + "'"+ "," + "'dd-MM-yyyy')," + "'"+ job_id + "'"+ ","  + salary + ","+ comm_pt + "," + manager + "," + department_id + ")",
    function(err,result){
        if (!err){
            console.log("success")
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })


});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

my EJS template is a normal form as below:

```
<% include partials/header.ejs %>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="add-player-form" action="/addemployee" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job" id="job" placeholder="job" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="comm" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose comm PT</option>
                        <option>0.1</option>
                        <option>0.2</option>
                        <option>0.3</option>
                        <option>0.4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="manager" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose manager ID</option>
                        <% for (var row = 0; row < players.rows.length; row++) { %>
                            <option><%= players.rows[row][0]%></option>
                        <% } %>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="salary" id="salary" placeholder="salary" required>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class = "form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="depart_id" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose dept ID</option>
                        <% for (var row = 0; row < players.rows.length; row++) { %>
                            <option><%= players.rows[row][1]%></option>
                        <% } %>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add Employee</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am trying to extract the values from the form in the request body but when I do a console log it returns me {}. I am pretty sure i have used the body parse correctly.

What am i doing wrong?

ps: still new to ejs and node js

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so the content type of the form submission is multipart/form-data which is usually used to upload files.But I don't see any file type input in above form.

So try removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your form. By default it will use `url-encoded` as the format.

In case, if you want to upload files, try [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for parsing your request.

Answer (score 0):

What i have seen looking into your code that you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
Try removing this code if you don't have to upload any image. multipart/form-data is generally used for uploading files or images.

I have removed your multupart/formdata and have made it as simple form and in case you want to upload files you can use either multer or skipper S3 based on your requirement.

```
<% include partials/header.ejs %>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="add-player-form" action="/addemployee" method="post">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job" id="job" placeholder="job" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="comm" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose comm PT</option>
                        <option>0.1</option>
                        <option>0.2</option>
                        <option>0.3</option>
                        <option>0.4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="manager" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose manager ID</option>
                        <% for (var row = 0; row < players.rows.length; row++) { %>
                            <option><%= players.rows[row][0]%></option>
                        <% } %>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="salary" id="salary" placeholder="salary" required>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class = "form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select id="depart_id" name="position" class="form-control" required>
                        <option selected disabled>Choose dept ID</option>
                        <% for (var row = 0; row < players.rows.length; row++) { %>
                            <option><%= players.rows[row][1]%></option>
                        <% } %>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add Employee</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```